# Work Manager's Periodic Work Request executing multiple requests for the same work at a given instance

Tags: android, multithreading, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I have a work manager in my android application and I am using it to implement a Period Work Request to send an email after every 15 minutes, however, sometimes, after 15 minutes, instead of 1 e-mail, multiple e-mails are sent for the same work. How can I fix this? I want to send just one e-mail for a particular work after 15 minutes given a certain condition in my `Worker` class.

**Worker class**

```
public class CloseFlight extends Worker {

    private FlightRepository flightRepo;
    public Context context;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter;
    LocalDateTime final_departure_time;

    String aircraft_type;



    public CloseFlight(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        this.flightRepo = new FlightRepository(context);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        String flightnumber = getInputData().getString("flightno");
        String date = getInputData().getString("departuredate");

        formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

        if(!(flightnumber==null || date == null)) {
            Flight flight_value = flightRepo.getFlight(flightnumber,date);

            String departure_time = flight_value.getFinal_departure_time();
            final_departure_time = LocalDateTime.parse(departure_time, formatter);

            String datetime_now = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
            LocalDateTime time_now = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime_now, formatter);


            long diffInMinutes = Duration.between(final_departure_time, time_now).toMinutes();
            String email_status = flight_value.getFlight_closure_status();


            \\I want this to be executed just once 
            if(diffInMinutes>60 && email_status.contentEquals("opened")) {

                aircraft_type = flight_value.getAircraft_type();

                String email = "Details " + "\n" + flightnumber + " " + date + "\n" + "\n" + "Date: " + " " + date + "\n" + "Aircraft Type: " + " " + aircraft_type;

                //Sending the email from here
                JavaMailAPI javaMailAPI = new JavaMailAPI(context, "myemailid@gmail.com", "Email for " + flightnumber + " and Departure date: " + date, email);
                javaMailAPI.execute();

                FlightClosureStatus flightClosureStatus = new FlightClosureStatus(flightnumber, date, "emailsent");
                flightRepo.updateFlightClosureStatus(flightClosureStatus);

            }

        }

        return Result.success();
    }


}
```

**Activity**

```
for(int i =0 ; i< length_report; i ++) {
    String status = reportitems.get(i).getStatus();


    if(status.contentEquals("opened")){
        String flightNumber = reportitems.get(i).getFlightNumber();
        String departureDate = reportitems.get(i).getDepartureDate();


        Data data = new Data.Builder()
            .putString("flightno", flightNumber)
            .putString("departuredate", departureDate).build();

        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();

        final PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest2 = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(CloseFlight.class,15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setInputData(data)
            .build();

        WorkManager workManager =  WorkManager.getInstance(ReportListingActivity.this);

        workManager.enqueue(periodicWorkRequest2);

        workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(periodicWorkRequest2.getId())
            .observe(ReportListingActivity.this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
                    if (workInfo != null) {
                        Log.d("periodicWorkRequest", "Status changed to : " + workInfo.getState());
                    }
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Look like you’re scheduling multiple periodic works (`length_report` that are open to be exact). So it makes sense that you’ll send `length_report` (just those which are open flights) emails each 15 minutes. Is this what you experience? Or do you get multiple emails for the same flight?

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel yes, I am scheduling multiple periodic works for different flights which are `opened`. In the `Worker` class, I check if the flight is opened, if it is, then only I send the e-mail, and once the email is sent, I change the status to `emailsent` in my Rooms database for the respective flight. However, I end up getting multiple emails for the same flight.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that work manager differentiate work by the worker class and since you use the same worker class so only the first job will be taken into account (with the same data, which contains the flight details in you case).

Meaning, when the first work is scheduled, all is good. But when you schedule the second one of the same worker - it will use the previous job again.

It’s OK to use the same worker class in different contexts, but you should let work manager know how to distinguish works from the same worker.

I recommend to use unique name, instead:

```
workManager.enqueue(periodicWorkRequest2);
```

Use this:

```
workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
    “UNIQUE_NAME”, // Maybe you should use the flight number?
    ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, // to not send mail if another being sent right now
    periodicWorkRequest2
);
```

Comment: In this case, what happens when the same flight (hence having the same flight number) is scheduled each day of the week? I want to send the email once for a flight before it departs each day.

Comment: Is the flight number and email have one-to-one relation? If so, one email will be sent per day. If it’s one-to-many relation (user can check in to multiple flights a day), single user can get multiple emails a day - one per flight. Of course you need to change the interval to 1 day.

Comment: I want all the flight details to go to one email address itself, hence I want to get the email for each flight once a day, but need to schedule a worker every 15 minutes to check for my specified condition based on which the email should be sent. Is there a way I can dispose off the job for that particular flight once the email has been sent?

Comment: You have `cancelUniqueWork` that accept the unique name as argument. You can use it so the periodic work should “kill” itself

Comment: Oh, where do I specifiy the 'cancelUniqueWork'? I want it to kill only when the criteria is fulfilled and email is sent.

Comment: It's a `WorkManager` function that cancel work by unique name, you can use it right after the mail is successfully sent

Comment: How will I know that the mail is successfully sent? I am sending the mail from my `Worker` class and not the activity

Comment: You can cancel your work from within the worker - the current work should not be interrupted.

Comment: How exactly can I achieve that within the worker without interrupting the current work? I need the worker class to be working forever, it is just that I want to cancel the work for a particular flight on a particular day once the email is sent based on the above condition inside the worker class.

Comment: I don’t quite understand the requirements of the background work, so I fear I cannot help you with that. But does my answer answers the original question (scheduling duplicates the first worker)?

Comment: What I mean is how can I cancel the work for a particular flight given the unique flight number and date?

Comment: It depends how to decide to name each work. For example, if each work is identified by the flight # and data pair you can create SHA1 hash of the date+flight number and use it as a unique name.

Comment: where shall I cancel the work - in my worker or in my activity? Because I only want to cancel after sending the e-mail, and I am sending the e-mail in the worker. So how can I cancel the work within the worker upon sending the e-mail?

Comment: At the end of `doWork()` function, right after successfully sending the email.

Comment: What will the syntax be for that, since I cannot call the `cancelUniqueWork' method there as my WorkManager is instantiated in the activity

Comment: You might get work manager with the application context. You can keep static reference of your application context without worrying about memory leak.